# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable In Python

Tags: python, regex

Bit of a python noob and I'm required to add a regular expression in my code but can not get it to work :/ i have searched the error message on google and tried to figure out whats wrong but no luck so i figured next best thing to do  would be to ask directly.
Here is the code so far:

```
# allows us to access a random 'key' in the dictionary
import random
import re

# Contains the question and it's correct answer
my_dict =   {
            "A form of Protectionism that imposes a tax on imports" : "tariff",
            "....is quantity of a good or service that consumers are willing and able to     buy at a given price in a given time period" : "Demand", 
            "....is the quantity of a good or service that a producer is willing and able   to supply onto the market at a given price in a given time period" : "Supply",
            "By using ..... businesses can bring down their average costs by producing on a larger scale" : "Economies of scale",
            "The cost of the next best alternative" : "Opportunity Cost",
            ".... is the transfer of assets from the public (government) sector to the private sector." : "Privatisation"
        }


# welcome message
print("Economics Revision App")
print("=======================")



# the quiz will end when this variable becomes 'False'
playing = True


# While the game is running
while playing == True:

    # set the score to 0
    score = 0

    # gets the number of questions the player wants to answer
    num = int(input("\nHow many questions would you like: "))
    num = re.match("r\d[0-9]{2}$", num())
    if match:
        print ('foo')

    # loop the correct number of times
    for i in range(num):

        # the question is one of the dictionary keys, picked at random
        question = (random.choice( list(my_dict.keys())))
        # the answer is the string mapped to the question key
        answer = my_dict[question]

        # print the question, along with the question number
        print("\nQuestion " + str(i+1) )
        print(question  + "?")

        # get the user's answer attempt
        guess = input("> ")

        # if their guess is the same as the answer
        if guess.lower() == answer.lower():
            # add 1 to the score and print a message
            print("Correct!")
            score += 1
        else:
            print("Incorrect guess again!")

    # after the quiz, print their final score  
    print("\nYour final score was " + str(score))

    # store the user's input...
    again = input("Enter any key to play again, or 'q' to quit.")

    #... and quit if they types 'q'
    if again.lower() == 'q':
        playing = False
```

The code I'm struggling with in questions

Comment: The next best thing is to look at the stacktrace for the exception to see which line the error occurred on. What do you think `num()` means in the line `num = re.match("r\d[0-9]{2}$", num())`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`num = re.match("r\d[0-9]{2}$", num())`

`num` is simply an interger, so `num()` is invalid.

Should be something like `match = re.match("r\d[0-9]{2}$", str(num))`

1) it should be `match` right?

2) `re` is working on `str`, so the argument passed should be `str(num)`

Then the code should be fine and fun as well. :)

Comment: Thanks it accpets the integer but now it wont run the loop of the program?

Comment: @user3080288 It actually works quite well on my computer. Are you following a correct indentation? Consider pasting the edited code in your question and run it after fixing the bugs.

Comment: Now im getting, **ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'g'**, any ideas?

Comment: @user3080288 How about checking with `isdigit()` before using `int()`